# How can I manually describe an example input for a java @RequestBody Map<String, String>?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, springfox

I am designing an api where one of the POST methods that takes a `Map<String, String>` of any key value pairs.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/start", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void startProcess(
    @ApiParam(examples = @Example(value = {
        @ExampleProperty(
            mediaType="application/json",
            value = "{\"userId\":\"1234\",\"userName\":\"JoshJ\"}"
        )
    }))
    @RequestBody(required = false) Map<String, String> fields) {
    // .. does stuff
}
```

I would like to provide an example input for `fields` but I can't seem to get it to render in the swagger output. Is this not the correct way to use `@Example`?

Comment: @ApiParam(value = "json", required = true,defaultValue = "{\"id\": \"1\",\"deviceToken\":\"1\"}",name = "json")

Comment: I am trying like above. but still not working. It is working for headers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swagger only provides the API, these annotations still have to be integrated into the Springfox framework to work. At the time this question was posted, neither `@ExampleProperty` nor `@Example` were supported by Springfox. This can be seen in [#853](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/853) and [#1536](https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1536).

Since version 2.9.0, this has been implemented. For an example, you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52634642/1915448).

Comment: still now there no solution ? please help me if it is there.

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar as you can see in the given links, the issue is still open. Right now the ticket is not in progress, but they're looking for contributions.

Comment: Can you show us the import for @ExampleProperty

Answer (score 11):

The issues mentioned in @g00glen00b's answer seems to be fixed. Here is a code snippet of how it can be done.

In your controller class:

```
// omitted other annotations
@ApiImplicitParams(
        @ApiImplicitParam(
                name = "body",
                dataType = "ApplicationProperties",
                examples = @Example(
                        @ExampleProperty(
                                mediaType = "application/json",
                                value = "{\"applicationName\":\"application-name\"}"
                        )
                )
        )
)
public Application updateApplicationName(
        @RequestBody Map<String, String> body
) {
    // ...
}

// Helper class for Swagger documentation - see http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#q27
public static class ApplicationProperties {

    private String applicationName;

    public String getApplicationName() {
        return applicationName;
    }

    public void setApplicationName(String applicationName) {
        this.applicationName = applicationName;
    }

}
```

Additionally, you need to add the following line to your Swagger config:

```
// omitted other imports...
import com.fasterxml.classmate.TypeResolver;

@Bean
public Docket api(TypeResolver resolver) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            // the following line is important!
            .additionalModels(resolver.resolve(DashboardController.ApplicationProperties.class));
}
```

Further documentation can be found here: http://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#q27

Comment: Agree this works, but its just ..blah.. Would be far better if `dataType = "ApplicationProperties"` could be omitted

Comment: Thanks, it works, but like @EvgeniAtanasov said, it would be better in we delete the model class!